# How to prepend lines with serial number in descending order using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

Currently I'm using `awk '{print NR,$0}'`  this command to print serial number for a file. But how to print serial number in descending order?

Current output:

```
1 abcd
2 abcd
3 abcd
4 abcd
```

Desired output:

```
4 abcd
3 abcd
2 abcd
1 abcd
```

Comment: Please edit your post to make the intention clearer. In your input example, all lines have the same content. This is a problem because we cannot distuinguish whether the lines should be in the original order, and prepended with "down-counting" line numbers, or if you want to simply prepend "normal" line numbers and then print _everything_ in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '{ a[i++]=NR" "$0 } END { for (n=i-1;n>=0;) print a[n--] }' input_file
```

Comment: @aastha I'm sorry but I am confused. This would simply print the input file in reverse order (albeit with the original line numbers attached). I thought the idea was to have the input file in normal order, and only the "serial numbers" in reverse order.

Comment: I'm new to this but this awk command was working for me  @AdminBee

Comment: @aastha If that is the case, please edit your question so that your requirements become clearer. The way it is formulated now is ambiguous, and all Q&A on this site are not only for the benefit of the person asking, but also of others who may be facing the same issue in the future (but who will also need to understand _if_ their problem is actually the same as yours).

Answer (score 4):

Not using `awk` but instead employing tools that would let you avoid doing your own (more detailed) scripting.

Using the non-standard `tac` utility to output the lines of a file in reverse order, and `cat` with its non-standard `-n` option to number lines:

```bash
tac file | cat -n | tac
```

Comment: `nl` if you don't have `cat -n`, perhaps

Comment: @roaima Well, `awk` would be better. `nl` have all sorts of ideas of what constitutes a "page", with headers and footers. If you just want a sequential numbering of all lines, `awk '{ printf "%5d %s\n", FNR, $0 }'` would be more reliable.

Comment: That would work too. `nl` is defined by POSIX as assuming an infinite logical page length (i.e. start at line 1 and keep going). I use it quite often for quick throwaway numbering.

Comment: @roaima I know, but it also interprets certain strings in the document as special, like `\:`, `\:\:` and `\:\:\:`. It also defaults to only numbering non-empty lines.

Comment: Many `tail` implementations have `-r` to do the same as GNU `tac`.

Answer (score 3):

*Note: This answer assumes that the goal is to have "down-counting" line numbers while keeping the original order of the text lines. The phrasing of the post and the provided example is ambiguous in that respect, so this answer may not solve the OP's actual problem.*

In order to avoid buffering, a double-pass approach might be beneficial for large files. It uses standard syntax, and so should be fairly portable.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{next} {printf "%d %s\n",(NR-2*FNR+1),$0}' input_file input_file
```

This will process the file twice (hence it is given twice as argument):

- In the first pass, where `FNR`, the per-file line counter, is the same as `NR`, the global line counter, we do nothing (=immediately skip execution to the `next` line) and simply have the line counters be auto-incremented.
- In the second pass (`FNR` now differs from `NR`), we calculate the inverse line number as `NR` (total number of lines processed, i.e. total lines in the input file plus the current line number) minus 2 times `FNR` (one times to reduce it to the file length, and another times to actually count down), plus 1 (otherwise we would end up with line number `0` for the last line), and use `printf` to prepend this to the line.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
$ raku -e 'my @a = lines(); put (@a.elems - $++, $_) for @a;' file
```

Sample Input:

```
Abcd
Bcde
Cdef
Defg
Efgh
Fghi
Ghij
```

Sample Output:

```
7 Abcd
6 Bcde
5 Cdef
4 Defg
3 Efgh
2 Fghi
1 Ghij
```

Briefly, `lines` are read into an `@`-sigiled array. Then these lines are `put` (*Print-Using-Terminator*) with a prepended index computed via `@a.elems - $++`. Raku's topic variable `$_` stands in for individual lines as they are returned from the `@a` array.

https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

Having below sample input:

```
one
two
three
```

If your input file is small enough that can fit into the amount of the current free memory you have and you also want to keep the order of the lines, then.

```
awk '{ data[NR]=$0 } 
END{ 
    for(recNr=NR; recNr>0; recNr--)
        print recNr, data[++c]
}' infile
```

Output:

```
3 one
2 two
1 three
```

---

or if you wanted to reverse the order of the input lines too, then.

```
awk '{ data[NR]=$0 } 
END{ 
    for(recNr=NR; recNr>0; recNr--)
        print recNr, data[recNr]
}' infile
```

Output:

```
3 three
2 two
1 one
```