# Reverse Eastern Arabic numbers at the end of each line

Tags: text-processing, locale

I have a file with 10,000 lines, and at the end of each line, there is a number, like:

```
asdf ggg ١
gghh rtt ٣٢٥
tyyu bnnn jigff ٢٧
```

Arrange the digits of all numbers in reverse order. The right order is:

```
asdf ggg ١
gghh rtt ٥٢٣
tyyu bnnn jigff ٧٢
```

Can you help me (please) to reverse the order of the numbers in each line?

[Eastern Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) digits:

(٠، ١، ٢، ٣، ٤، ٥، ٦، ٧، ٨، ٩)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/718224/how-to-prepend-lines-with-serial-number-in-descending-order-using-awk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Perl:

```bash
$ perl -CSD -pe 's/(\d+)$/reverse($1)/e' file
asdf ggg ١
gghh rtt ٥٢٣
tyyu bnnn jigff ٧٢
```

This applies a substitution command to each line of input.  The substitution matches any string of digits at the very end of the line.  Whatever string of digits is matched, the `reverse()` function is used to reverse it.  The result of the reversion is used as the replacement text in the substitution.

The trailing `/e` causes Perl to treat the `reverse($1)` as a command to evaluate.

The `-CSD` option to `perl` enables UTF-8 I/O.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's/ (\d+) $ /{flip($0)}/;'  file
```

OR

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's/ (\d+) $ /{$0.flip}/;'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
asdf ggg ١
gghh rtt ٣٢٥
tyyu bnnn jigff ٢٧
```

Sample Output:

```
asdf ggg ١
gghh rtt ٥٢٣
tyyu bnnn jigff ٧٢
```

The Raku solution above is similar to the Perl solution already posted, however one notable difference is Unicode is handled gracefully in Raku by default (no extra command line flags to remember). Captures start from `$0` in Raku. Keywords are somewhat different in Raku (more precise?): to flip the letters of a string use the `flip` keyword; to reverse the order of a list use the `reverse` keyword.

Code blocks within regexes are denoted by `{ … }` curlie braces. When learning Raku, if you use the Perl(5) `/e` flag you get a nice message:

```
Unsupported use of /e.  In Raku please use: interpolated {...} or s{} =
...  form
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org